# PHP mysql_num_rows() not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a mysql database with absolutely no values or rows, and when I call mysql_num_rows(), it returns like the table has got the row.

I've tried everything I could thought about, but didn't work.
I post the code:

```
function test_input($data){
            $data = trim($data);
            $data = stripslashes($data);
            $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        }
...
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
$lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
$uname = test_input($_POST["uname"]);
$password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
$password = md5($password);

$q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '$uname'");
if(mysql_num_rows($q2) > 0){
    echo "<p>Sorry, that username already exists</p>";
}
...
```

Comment: Goodness no, please don't use MD5 to hash your passwords. And mysql_ functions have been officially deprecated. Please look into using MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: *"with absolutely no values or rows"* - Like a "totally empty" table with "absolutely nothing"? If there exists any rows at all, then that could be the issue here. DB schema is required here. Note that if you have NULL values, NULL != empty.

Comment: Share test_input function

Comment: I've got a table with the name, last name, email, username, password; but there are no rows, bcz no user has registered to my webpage, as it's giving me this error. @Fred-ii- any solution?

Comment: okey @Rishi but it works on another page and gives no errors

Comment: Yep in the least you want to salt your password with some long arbitrary secret string and start using mysqli functions instead or better yet, PDO.

Comment: @Adrià when you do a `SELECT *` you are also checking against any rows that could contain data where others are empty or NULL. Do an actual column selection instead. I.e.: `SELECT uname ...` and see what that produces. You could also use `COUNT(column)` instead.

Comment: Could also use `LIMIT 1` since we're only expecting one result

Comment: didn't work @Fred-ii-

Comment: And don't ever alter a user's password. You're attempting to run/running the user's password through a function that strip's slashes, trim's white space, and converts *special* characters. Leave the password alone (other than hashing it using `password_hash()` or something of the like). Even though, if you were to run the password through the same function in every case required, it's still bad practice. If you forgot to run it through even one time, the login system will not work as the password will not match that in the database.

Comment: @Adrià You know you can do away with all those functions and just use a prepared statement in mysqli_ or PDO since what you're using isn't all that safe against an SQL injection really. That mysql_ API is deprecated also and you may eventually be forced to stop using it. You'll then need to do a total rewrite, which is not always fun to do, *just saying* ;-)

Comment: and seeing the error you posted below; skip all that code and use a prepared statement; *end of story, success*. That custom function does nothing to safeguard you.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords with MD5 as thats barely better than plain-text.

Comment: I know this comes ages late, since "mysql_" functions are deprecated, you know you can just do "if (mysql_num_rows(mysql(query('your query'))))" right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return from test_input function

```
  function test_input($data){
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
```

Also do mind as terry commented.
 don't use md5 for password and use pdo or mysqli for db connection.

Comment: Yeees... this could be it

Comment: Actually, it worked! Thank you so much.
But... i'm getting a mysql error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE uname = 'admin'' at line 1`. Solution? (I'm VERY new to PHP and mysql ahhah)

Comment: *"and use pdo or mysqli for db connection."* - Using MySQLi_ or PDO on their own doesn't safeguard against an SQL injection.

Comment: As I'm doing this webpage for testing and for my friends, I don't care about SQL injections, yet :)

Comment: Could someone plz tell me what I gotta do with my error? :/

Comment: @Adrià Error, what error? oh that... well I can't see why you accepted the answer here, since you still have errors.

Comment: echo "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE \`uname\` = '$uname'" what query you are getting ?

Comment: I don't understand the question :| @Rishi

Comment: After `$password = md5($password);` print your generated query by echo that I given.

Comment: Funny how the new issue only came about once the `test_input()` function started doing its *thing*.

Comment: @Aparna But now the string-based field is *unquoted*.

Comment: @Aparna nah, it's not that, as I've got some more queries on other pages and they work perfectly, and are like this

Comment: @Aparna no no no, that is a string not an integer. Please remove that comment. It's wrong and misleading.

Comment: @Rishi I get `Resource id #10`

Comment: I think you printed $q2 not query please again check my comment and share only generated query.

Comment: Use filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); There's more to that input that you're missing, including MySQL injection risks. You can use filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); for the email post. See below on my answer post.

Comment: This function should not exist. I cannot condone "fixing" it.

Comment: @Adrià "I don't care about SQL injections, yet" is the wrong attitude. You're learning how to program, so learn how to do it *properly*. Shortcuts like this impair your learning and understanding and can instil bad habits that may very well cost you, your company, or people you know severely.

Comment: Everybody, I'm here to solve an error, not to argue with people about whether to use md5 or not, or to prevent injections. I'm a begginer, I'm still learning PHP and I will do whatever I gotta do to not be injected later on, everything by its time. My attitude is: until I dont finish a thing, I dont pass to the other one so, if you just don't know how to solve it, dont comment

Comment: @Adrià and you're doing all this for what then? You're using technology that's over 30 years old and will NOT be of any use for modern-day usage. You're wasting your time as others also. We're here to offer you help for the real world today and not as it was 30 years ago. If you're going to be obtuse about this, then go ahead. I for one am now moving on and I really hope that you have at least learned something here. Good luck.

Comment: I ONLY KNOW HOW TO SOLVE MY ERROR. I said I was going to keep on my project and my learning after I solve my error, I don't need people on the internet telling me what to do a hundred times, I've got my parents for that. Im gonna learn PHP frameworks and improve my code later on, for now I only want it to work. Hope you understand. @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Adrià There is no need to shout. Keep on learning the old crap, it'll get you nowhere.

Comment: Omg, u dont understand nothing do u? @Fred-ii- I said I am new, and the old school methods are the first things I found on the internet and, as they are simple, I started learning them, and when I solve all of my errors, I'll move to the good-new ones. 4 the moment, I only whant a solution to my freaking error, do u understand that?

Comment: But what Fred is telling you, why bother learning it the wrong, old and outdated way first? Why not, instead, learn to do it the better way? Your approach is basically to do everything twice. I understand what you want, to fix your errors, but we're only trying to help you - *for free*, by giving advice on how it should be. A lot of people here are very knowledgeable and competent about programming, and helping fresh programmers like yourself. Take the advice that is given to you, and don't get mad for someone trying to help you..

Comment: @Qirel any way to fix the errors? If not, could you please tell me some resources to learn this ways plz?

Comment: @Rishi `echo mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `uname` = '$uname'");` returns `Resouce id #10`

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how giving additional advice isn't desired you don't need a custom function to sanitize your entries.

```
$uname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'uname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

For more info, check out

[Filter_Input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) and [Sanatize Filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: What is this `accountlocked()` function and how does OP use it? (I know what it does, but you don't explain how it's used; it's just *code bloat* right now) Your answer is lacking a whole lotta detail on what you did, why you did it, and how to use it. And [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is more suitable choice over `hash()` as pointed out in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Comment: Good point but the login function does sort of self-explain that. If the OP wants more details I can dive deeper with the comment notes. Given that he's/she's got a basic idea of how these SQL Queries work with PHP, I wasn't going to assume his/her intelligence. Also, I didn't know about the password_hash/password_verify functions... So cheers for that :)

Comment: It's too night/day from OP's code. Complete rewrite without detail. You've added Mysqli (OOP), `filter_input()`, new password-hashing mechanism, function to lock the user out, sessions, etc. All OP needed was `return $data;` in the `test_input()` lol But kudos for the rewrite. With greater detail into how it works, and why you did what you did, it could be a viable option/learning tool for OP.

Comment: Can you trim this down? Dumping a metric ton of code into an answer does not make it a good answer.